# BackboneJS: What is options || (options = {}); in Backbone source code

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I was going through BackboneJS source code and was unable to figure out what this line 
`options || (options = {});` does, since there is not assignment to a variable.

Following is the code snippet from BackboneJS.

```
  var Model = Backbone.Model = function(attributes, options) {
    var attrs = attributes || {};
    options || (options = {});
    this.cid = _.uniqueId('c');
    this.attributes = {};
    if (options.collection) this.collection = options.collection;
    if (options.parse) attrs = this.parse(attrs, options) || {};
    attrs = _.defaults({}, attrs, _.result(this, 'defaults'));
    this.set(attrs, options);
    this.changed = {};
    this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But there *is* an assignment in there:

```
options || (options = {});
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^ Right there
```

So if `options` is falsey, the `options = { }` part will be executed. Since `options` is specified to be an object or `undefined` (i.e. not passed at all), an object is truthy, and `undefined` is falsey, that expression will do nothing if `options` is specified and set `options = { }` if `options` is not passed. That expression is just a different way of writing:

```
if(!options)
    options = { };
```

Keep in mind that an expression also qualifies as a statement in JavaScript so you can say things like:

```
1 + 2;
'where is' + ' pancakes house?';
```

in JavaScript; those two do nothing at all but `options || (options = { })` has an assignment as a side effect. Presumably `options || (options = { })` is evocative of the `options ||= { }` syntax that is available in many languages — but **not** in JavaScript — so the notation is easy for the Backbone authors to read.

Comment: that's a new learning for me haven't seen this elsewhere before.